# Know the change made in the Change History

Tags: wordpress, contacts, settings, system-settings

I can see the history of the people who have modified the contact and when they did it, but...
How do **I know what this change is?**

For an administrator it is important to know what modifications were made.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/setup/logging. You would need to turn on that optional feature.